# Returning a value from store procedure and outputing in XML

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have created this store procedure that returns the primary key of the table. I am calling this store procedure in a web service and passing through data from an XML document. I want to output the returned primary key in XML format on the web service to confirm the data was update in the database. The code for the store procedure:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateGamePlay]
    @GamePlayID int,
    @ParticipantID int,
    @GameVersionID int,
    @GameID int,
    @GameScenarioID int,
    @Start DateTime,
    @End DateTime,
    @Success varchar(10)
    AS
    UPDATE GamePlay
    SET 
    ParticipantID = @ParticipantID,GameVersionID = @GameVersionID,GameID = @GameID,GameScenarioID = @GameScenarioID,StartDateTime = @Start,EndDateTime = @End,Success = @Success
    WHERE GamePlayID = @GamePlayID
    RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

The webservice assigns the data in the XML to local variables and inserts it into the database. I want to get the return type and display it in XML on the web service.

```
[WebMethod]
        public void AddGamePlayData()
        {
            XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
            xd.Load(@"C:\Users\bradleya\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Web Services\Web Services\addGame.xml");
            XmlNode documentNode = xd.SelectSingleNode("/GamePlayData/GamePlay");

            int ParticipantID = Convert.ToInt32(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("ParticipantID").InnerText);
            int GameVersionID = Convert.ToInt32(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("GameVersionID").InnerText);
            int GameID = Convert.ToInt32(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("GameID").InnerText);
            int GameSenarioID = Convert.ToInt32(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("GameScenarioID").InnerText);
            DateTime Start = Convert.ToDateTime(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("Start").InnerText);
            DateTime End = Convert.ToDateTime(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("End").InnerText);
            Boolean success = Convert.ToBoolean(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("Success").InnerText);

            SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection();
            oConn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=SNICKERS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VervePhaseOne;Integrated Security=True";
            oConn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = oConn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "addGamePlay";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParticipantID", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmd.Parameters["@ParticipantID"].Value = ParticipantID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GameVersionID", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmd.Parameters["@GameVersionID"].Value = GameVersionID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GameID", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmd.Parameters["@GameID"].Value = GameID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GameScenarioID", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmd.Parameters["@GameScenarioID"].Value = GameSenarioID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Start", SqlDbType.DateTime));
            cmd.Parameters["@Start"].Value = Start;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@End", SqlDbType.DateTime));
            cmd.Parameters["@End"].Value = End;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@success", SqlDbType.Bit));
            cmd.Parameters["@success"].Value = success;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

I have tried to change the return type to object and use the following code however its not working:

```
DataSet oDS = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter oCMD = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            oCMD.Fill(oDS, "GamePlay");
            return oDS.GetXml();
```

---EDIT---

The error when I use the fix I thought should work is that the XML should contain a integer as thats what should return however it returns this XML instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<anyType xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" d1p1:type="q1:string" xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<NewDataSet />
</anyType>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by `Not Working`?  Error messages?  Unexpected results?  Please be specific and include full information.

Comment: sorry, updated with XML results, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a function if you want a return value, otherwise use a select statement to ouptut your result.

Something like this:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateGamePlay]
    @GamePlayID int,
    @ParticipantID int,
    @GameVersionID int,
    @GameID int,
    @GameScenarioID int,
    @Start DateTime,
    @End DateTime,
    @Success varchar(10)
AS
    UPDATE GamePlay
    OUTPUT INSERTED.GamePlayID
    SET 
    ParticipantID = @ParticipantID,GameVersionID = @GameVersionID,GameID = @GameID,GameScenarioID = @GameScenarioID,StartDateTime = @Start,EndDateTime = @End,Success = @Success
WHERE GamePlayID = @GamePlayID
```